# Retornar y Transmitir Archivos PDF desde AWS S3 en NestJS

Tags: pdf, aws, stream, amazon-s3, nestjs

Estoy buscando orientación sobre cómo retornar y transmitir archivos PDF desde AWS S3 como respuestas HTTP en mi aplicación. Actualmente, estoy enfrentando un problema específico.

Sé que AWS S3 no proporciona una forma directa de retornar más de un objeto a la vez, pero mi principal desafío es cómo transmitir estos archivos PDF una vez que los he obtenido de S3.

Mi objetivo es obtener múltiples archivos PDF desde S3, combinarlos en uno solo y luego enviar este PDF combinado como respuesta HTTP en mi aplicación. Hasta ahora, no he logrado encontrar una solución efectiva para lograr esto.

Estoy utilizando nestJS, stream para trasmitir los pdf y el sdk de amazon. Lo que hago es simple, obtengo la informacion necesaria que necesitare para traer el archivo lo itero uno a uno ya que son varios los que recibo, los retorno todo es una promeso obteniendo un array de Buffer y ese array lo intento concatenar para luego trasmitirlo, pero creo que no lo estoy haciendo de la forma correcta, ya que al obtener el resultado me devuelve el primer pdf pero no los demas, yo esperaria que si yo solicite 3 archivos me devuelva los tres archivos en la respuesta que genera. Además de que tengo que tomar en cuenta en optimizar la respuesta del pdf, con ello me refiero a usar de la mejor forma los recursos al trasmitir el pdf.

```
  async findPdfFromBucketAndLocal(ids: string[], estiloCausasHorizontal?: boolean, res?: Response) {

    const solicitudes = (await this.solicitudesService.findByForReportUsCorrelative(ids)) as SolicitudDocument[];

    const request = solicitudes.map((item) => {
      const servicio = item?.['servicio']?.['nombre_servicio'];
      const key = `${process.env.MAIN_FOLDER}/${PathKeys.PREVIEW_SOLICITUDES}/${servicio}/${item?.correlativo_solicitud}.pdf`;
      return this.uploadFilesService.getObjectFromS3(key);
    });

    const pdfBuffers = await Promise.all(request);

    const buffers = pdfBuffers.map(item=>item.Body as Buffer)
    const pdfBuffer = Buffer.concat(buffers);

    return this.pdfService.pdfResponse(pdfBuffer, res)

  }

async getObjectFromS3(url: string) {
    const params = {
        Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: url
    };
    const request = await this.s3.getObject(params).promise()

    return request;
}



pdfResponse(pdfBuffer: Buffer, res: Response) {
    const stream = new Readable();

    stream.push(pdfBuffer);
    stream.push(null);

    res.set({
      'Content-Type': 'application/pdf ; charset=utf-8',
      'Content-Length': pdfBuffer.length,
    });

    stream.pipe(res);
  }
```

¿Alguien tiene alguna sugerencia o enfoque para lograr este objetivo? ¡Cualquier ayuda será muy apreciada!

¡Gracias de antemano!